# How to leave a virtual directory after uninstall

Tags: wix

I have a Web Site created in IIS.  I want to create a virtual directory under it and then another one under that.  When I uninstall, I only want to uninstall the last virtual directory if there's something in the first virtual directory.  (I don't care either way if there isn't - can uninstall or can leave it.)

```
-Website
|-VirtualDirectory1
||-VirtualDirectory2
```

Here is my current component:

```
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
  <!-- Setup IIS. -->
  <Fragment>
    <!-- Since these are outside of a component, they're not being created, just referenced.
         http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/01/25/install-a-new-virtual-directory-to-default-web-site-with-wix.aspx -->
    <iis:WebSite Id="Services" Description="Services">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="ServicesBindings" Header="[Hostname]" Port="80" />
    </iis:WebSite>
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="ToolkitServicesAppPool" Name="Toolkit Services" />

    <ComponentGroup Id="IISComponents" Directory="InstallDirectory">
      <Component Id="Toolkit.Services.App" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" KeyPath="yes">
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="ToolkitDir" Alias="Toolkit" Directory="Toolkit" WebSite="Services">
          <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="AppDir" Alias="App" Directory="InstallDirectory">
            <iis:WebApplication Id="AppApp" Name="App" WebAppPool="ToolkitServicesAppPool" />
          </iis:WebVirtualDir>
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

You can't put a WebVirtualDir under the WebSite because they're not allowed outside of Components, so I can't create VirtualDirectory1 manually and use it.  I also tried to use WebDir to define VirtualDirectory1 (randomly), but you can't define a WebVirtualDir under a WebDir.  There's no way to reference a virtual directory, so I can't drop it into a permanent component and just reference it from another.

This has basically been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077205/wix-how-to-skip-removing-of-iiswebvirtualdir-if-virtual-directory-contains-nes) but with no answer.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

1. Create a permanent component that contains the root vdir. Or you can share the component among several products, then the root vdir won't be deleted while all the products are not uninstalled.
2. Create another component with alias "root_vdir_name/new_vdir_name".

   ```
   <Component Id="Toolkit.Services.App" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" KeyPath="yes" Permanent="yes">
     <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="ToolkitDir" Alias="Toolkit" Directory="Toolkit" WebSite="Services" />
   </Component>

   <Component Id="Toolkit.Services.App" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" KeyPath="yes">
     <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="AppDir" Alias="Toolki/App" Directory="InstallDirectory" WebSite="Services">
       <iis:WebApplication Id="AppApp" Name="App" WebAppPool="ToolkitServicesAppPool" />
     </iis:WebVirtualDir>
   </Component>
   ```